# Guarantee of matrix inverse for $A'A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, least-squares

Suppose I have a matrix $A$. Let $A'$ be the transpose of A. Is there any guarantee that $A'A$ has an inverse?

You can find this formula at Adaptive Neuro-Fuzzy Inference System (ANFIS) theory in "LSE Recursive" part. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the formula $A^TA$ is very common in all linear algebra, the reference to this (rather obscure IMHO) ANFIS theory doesn't add much to the question. What you can say in general is that $A^TA$ is positive semidefinite, which in turn gives you that all eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are nonnegative. However, some eigenvalues might well vanish. In this case $A^TA$ is not invertible. You need to impose some constraint on $A$ that rules out the possibility of vanishing eigenvalues for $A^TA$.

Comment: So, A' * A also has inverse?

Comment: I write $A^TA $ to mean what you call $A'A$. The answer to this question therefore is in my last comment.

Comment: Welcome to M.SE! Tags should describe the problem, not the context in which the problem was encountered. Accordingly, I have removed two of your tags. I've also edited your title to be more descriptive and added MathJax to your formulae to make them clearer. I've also removed the note about A' * A being matrix multiplication because I think that's clear. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much, T. Gunn.

Comment: The guarantee is usually along the lines of "$\rm A$ has full column rank", i.e., its columns are linearly independent.

Answer (score 6):

I will write $A^TA$ instead of $A'A$. The matrix $A^TA$ has inverse if and only if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. Indeed, such a matrix is the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of the columns of $A$.

Comment: But now I remember that in the recursive least squares estimator (LSE) which ANFIS uses said that the parameters are linear combination. Maybe you know about least-square estimator that uses inverse of $A^TA$

Comment: @YohanesSetiawan: I second the suggestion of Priebe109 to look for "pseudoinverse matrix". Most probably, that's the concept in use in the things you are doing. **ADDED**: [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD)